# Markov Chain and conditional distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

I am reading "Modeling basketball play-by-play data" written by Petar Vracar, Erik Strumbelj, and Igor Kononenko.  I am having trouble understanding a certain statistical forumla, because I have no stats training.  The part I am having trouble with regards conditional distribution.  Here is the paragraph in the paper:

To simulate a match, we sample a Markov Chain $(x_0,x_1,...,x_n)$, where $x_o$ is start of the match and $x_n$ the end.  Let $f(y|x)$ be the distribution of $X_{n+1}$ given $X_n$.  Each vector is encoded as $<evt,qtr,time,ptsdif,a,h>$, where $evt$ is current game related event, $qrt$ and $time$ the current quarter and time left, $ptsdif$ is the point difference, and $a$ and $h$ are vectors with the two team's characteristics.  Among all of the components in the description of each state $x_i$, there are only two random variables: $evt$ and the duration of that event (in playing time, a continuous variable $dur$), since score differential and time left in game are direct consequence of these two variables.  This allows us to simplify modeling by factorizing the **conditional distribution**: $$f(y|x) = f_{Y^{(evt)}|X}(y^{(evt)}|x)f_{Y^{(dur)}|X,Y^{(evt)}}(y^{(dur)}|x,y^{(evt)}) $$  This conditional distribution can be estimated using two models, $M_{evt}$ that estimates the marginal conditional distribution for the next event given the current state description, and model $M_{dur}$ that estimates the time between two events given the current state description.  The models can be inferred separately.  To generate a sample from the joint distribution $f$ (that is to simulate the next state) we, in sequence, draw samples from these two marginal distribution models. END

I am quite confused as to where this formula came from and what it even means.  Can I get some help on either helping understand what this formula represents, or a resource that can help me understand?  Thanks.

Comment: Of course, your quote is taken out of context. But just reading the part you show, I am not surprised that you are confused. I have taught a lot of courses on Markov Chains and I can't make much sense of it either. By reading previous material where the notation is explained, and carefully  taking one step at a time up to where the quote appears, I might succeed.